# node.js - global variable not working?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a problem. The log says that the variable "gData" isnt defined. But in my opinion it must be, because its global? Can you help please?

```
function refreshGroupData(){
        groupModel.count(function(err, count){
        gData = count;
        io.sockets.emit( 'sendGroupData', gData);
    });
        console.log ('Test: ' + gData);
    }
```

Thanks, Robert.

Edit:

```
function refreshGroupData(){
        function test(callback){
            groupModel.count(function(err, count){
                callback(count)
            });
        }
        test(function(count) {
            io.sockets.emit( 'sendGroupData', count);
            console.log('Test: ' + count);
        });
}
```

Comment: Is that your complete code sample?

Comment: no. its only a function that i call in my code.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're referencing the value of the global `gData` variable before you set it.

Because you don't declare `gData`, its value cannot be evaluated until `gData = count;` is executed.  And because that line is executed within the asynchronous `groupModel.count(...)` callback, the `console.log(...)` line is executed before that happens.

If you move the `console.log` call inside the callback, it will work.

```
function refreshGroupData() {
    groupModel.count(function(err, count) {
        gData = count;
        io.sockets.emit('sendGroupData', gData);
        console.log('Test: ' + gData);
    });
}
```

The proper way to do this sort of thing is like this:

```
function refreshGroupData(callback) {
    groupModel.count(function(err, count) {
        io.sockets.emit('sendGroupData', count);
        callback(count);
    });
}

// Calling the function and logging the result.
refreshGroupData(function(count) {
    console.log('Test: ' + count);
});
```

Comment: Ahh ok, i know that it worked inside. But i need it outside, because i will use the variable for some other stuff. is there a way to use it outside? how can i check that the function is ready?

Comment: @nofear87 You would change `refreshGroupData` to accept a callback parameter that it will call with the count once it's available, passing the count to it as a parameter.  See updated answer.

Comment: thank you, thats nearly, what iam searching for ;-) can i use the callback in the groupModel.count function too? so that i can use the variable in the refresh function and not only outside? i hope you understand me

Comment: @nofear87 Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I am sorry to, i cant explain it better. Can you maybe show me how you implement the wait for the callback and the console.log?

Comment: thank you! i search a way to do this in my refresh function. in my start post you see my try. is there a better way? i need the callback because the database query is asynchron, right? i only will understand it :D

Answer (score 1):

gData variable is inside the anonymous function.. so it is local to that function.

Comment: ok, i thought declaration "var gData" is local and "gData" is global. so i dont understand it :D is there a way to get it readable outside the function?

Comment: declaring outside the refreshGroupData function is one option.

Comment: i have tested it, but it didnt working...it wont be overwritten by the refreshgroupData function :(

Comment: Declaring the variable `gData` outside the function will make it available when you're trying to log it, but since `groupModel.count()` is an async routine, the value isn't set when you access it. You'll have to log when the routine has completed. To ensure that, you'll have to access the variable inside `groupModel.count()`'s callback routine.